# Custom cursor issue with nested movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6

I made a custom cursor and add mouse event listeners to it, so it can animate according to mouse clicks (Up/Down) and also hide after 4 seconds if the user didn't click or move the mouse.

The custom cursor was working OK, but after loading external SWF to the container I found that custom cursor event listeners is not working with all movie clips on the child SWF (external loaded SWF). So It is not animating with mouse events and not resetting hide timer, which causing mouse to hide even if the user are moving or clicking it.

The hierarchy of movie clips as follows:

```
           -- Scene 1
             -- container's Buttons and controls MCs
                -- myLoader content  //added under the controls MC
                  -- content_mc  //contains the child movie clips
                    -- child's movie clips //contains animations and simple buttons
```

I tried to set 
myLoader.mouseChildren = false;
This solves the custom cursor issue but also blocked all mouse events on the child SWF and make all child's buttons unclickable.

So, I wonder if you can help me finding a way to make the custom cursor events working with the nested movie clips without blocking the nested movie clips mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

You should find that if you place the listener at the top level class and set capture to true you should get all the events you need

Comment: Already did that and put all listeners at the top level of the container but unfortunately I got events from container and top level only of the loaded child

Comment: hmm Okay, have you tried setting mouse children to true but mouse enabled to false on the child object?